# When using conditional rendering, how do I prevent repeating the child components on each condition?

Tags: vue.js

**Scenario**

I have a custom button component in Vue:

```html
<custom-button type="link">Save</custom-button>
```

This is its template:

```js
// custom-button.vue
<template>
  <a v-if="type === 'link'" :href="href">
    <span class="btn-label"><slot></slot></span>
  </a>
  <button v-else :type="type">
    <span class="btn-label"><slot></slot></span>
  </button>
</template>
```

You can see from the template that it has a `type` prop. If the type is `link`, instead of the `<button>` element, I am using `<a>`.

**Question**

You'll notice from the template that I repeated the child component, i.e. `<span class="btn-label"><slot></slot></span>` on both root components. How do I make it so that I won't have to repeat the child components?

In JSX, it's pretty straightforward. I just have to assign the child component to a variable:

```js
const label = <span class="btn-label">{text}</span>

return (type === 'link') 
  ? <a href={href}>{label}</a>
  : <button type={type}>{label}</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, I would probably opt to write the render function directly since the template is small (with or without [JSX](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx)), but if you want to use a template then you can [use the `<component>` component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to dynamically choose what you want to render as that element, like this:

```js
Vue.component('custom-button', {
  template: '#custom-button',
  props: [
    'type',
    'href',
  ],
  computed: {
    props() {
      return this.type === 'link'
        ? { is: 'a', href: this.href }
        : { is: 'button', type: this.type };
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-button type="button">Button</custom-button>
  <custom-button type="submit">Submit</custom-button>
  <custom-button type="link" href="http://www.google.com">Link</custom-button>
</div>

<template id="custom-button">
  <component v-bind="props">
    <span class="btn-label"><slot></slot></span>
  </component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could always create a locally registered component...

```
// in custom-button.vue
components : {
    'label' : {template : '<span class="btn-label"><slot></slot></span>'}
}
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. But do note that [Vue full build](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds) is required for template compilation.

Comment: What does this mean in practice? If you're using a build tool, the template will be compiled during the build, no?

Comment: No. For e.g. Vue has a [full version](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.min.js) and a [runtime version](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.runtime.js). Runtime build is 30% smaller than the full build. This [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/zf90mhh6/1/) is using the runtime version. You may try to use `template` property and it won't work. In a typical vue-cli project, Runtime build is used by default. The code in `<template></template>` is compiled by `vue-loader`, not by vue directly.

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing (crosses fingers). Templates are compiled by vue-loader during the build. If you're not using vue-loader, you shouldn't be using Vue runtime version.